# Intuition for the Positive Real Number $\epsilon$ in Topology

Tags: general-topology, intuition, epsilon-delta, motivation

Although this question might sound a little too simple, it is a problem that I must get addressed. In addition, there is no way for me to formally describe it. If you have something you can add, by all means; add it to my question to help me gain the answer I am looking for.

---

After pondering over this following definition on $\epsilon$-balls, I was not able to grasp the intuition for $\epsilon$ generally speaking:

**Definition ($\epsilon$-balls).** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. For each point $x\in{X}$ and each real number $\epsilon>0$, let
$$B_d(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in{X}:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$$
be the $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ in $(X,d)$.

For this definition and any other topological definition involving the universal notion of $\epsilon$, I was not able to grasp its effect and meaning and how it affects the definition. I am also trying to come up with an example pertaining to the above definition but cannot think of any.

Moving forward, I want an intuition for the use of $\epsilon$ for topology and other higher mathematics. I see $\epsilon$ is numerous important proofs, definitions and theorems. And if I do not know how to use them or understand why/how they are there, I will be in trouble when it comes to more complicated subject matters.

Comment: There is nothing to this $\varepsilon$, you could just call it $b$ or $\beta$ or $\mathfrak{JULIAN}$ or whatever. it just stands for the radius. so it is often called $r$ or $R$ or $\mathcal{R}$. You should read some $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs, as they are called, then you will understand how you use it

Comment: Not quite sure if that's what you have in mind, but $\epsilon$ (and $\delta$) are usually imagined to be _very very small_ quantites. That's just a convention, though - you could replace $\epsilon$ by any variable name really.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're asking, but $\epsilon$ is a number.  That's it, nothing else.  The $\epsilon$-ball centred at $x$ is the set of all points whose distance from $x$ is less than $\epsilon$.  For example in $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual metric, a $1$-ball is just an open disc of radius $1$.

Comment: As you can see from the three more-or-less differing answers in these comments, you should consider **clarifying** your question.

Comment: @Laters However, it says "for all $\epsilon$" and and my thinking is that it does not work "for all". Could you provide me with an example as described in my question?

Comment: The "for each $\epsilon$" merely refers to the fact that a ball can have any (positive) radius you want.  Your source might have expressed the definition a bit better as "Let $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$.  Then $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ is...".

Comment: @David Well, say I take $X$ to equal the closed interval $[0,1]$. What do I intuistically go from there? (sorry if this is a too basic question)

Comment: @AlexR ^^ (I am tagging you for the above statement as well)

Comment: @JulianRachman: it is not an open subset of $\mathbf{R}$: consider the vertex $0$. There is no ball about $0$ that is entirely contained in $[0,1]$,  because if $r>0$ is arbitrary, $B_r(1)\cap[0,1]\neq\emptyset$. (Here $B_r(1)=B_d(1;r)$ in your notation, where $d$ is the standard metric on $\mathbf{R}$.)

Comment: In $X=[0,1]$ we have for example$$B(0.5,0.1)=(0.4,0.6)$$and$$B(0.9,0.2)=(0.7,1]\ .$$

Comment: @Laters Then take $(0,1)$ which is open

Comment: @David Which each is less than $\epsilon$? I still do not know WHY they work under the conditions that it is "$<\epsilon$.

Comment: @JulianRachman yes exactly. can you prove this formally? doing this kind of stuff is the best way to get used to it

Comment: @Laters But when I think about choosing any $\epsilon>0$, I think of like "anything." That is what's wrong! I do not know how to think of it in a more refined manner.

Comment: @JulianRachman perhaps go to the definition of continuity and uniform continuity, compare them and draw pictures. if you think of like anything, then you are exactly right. if you say "let $\varepsilon>0$" then $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary but fixed

Comment: @Laters So I have seen that $\epsilon$ is a real number that is basically is a very small number in any interval and is greater than $0$. Am I right? Then how do you go about selecting "$\epsilon$."

Comment: @David I inputted your example into the definition and got this:$$B_d(0.5,0.1)=\{0.6\in[0,1]:d(0.4,0.6)<0.1\}.$$ Which is obviously wrong. But why? I think it is right but I think I inputted it wrong or I am thinking of things in the wrong way.

Comment: In this example, $x$ is $0.5$ and $\epsilon$ is $0.1$, and $y$ is still a variable:$$B_d(0.5,0.1)=\{y\in[0,1]\colon d(0.5,y)<0.1\}\ ,$$which is $(0.4,0.6)$.

Comment: @David I see it now!!

Comment: @David So how did you choose $\epsilon$? And is $(0.4,0.6)$ a coordinate or what? And how do you get $(0.4,0.6)$?

Comment: See my earlier comment, $\epsilon$ is **any positive number**, $0.1$ is just an example.

Comment: @David But what if you pick $\epsilon=0.0000001$?

Comment: And what value do you want to pick for $x$?

Comment: @David $0.0001$

Comment: Do you understand what the expression $d(y,0.0001)$ means?

Comment: @David it is a distance metric between $y$ and $0.0001$

Comment: Can you give an algebraic formula for it?

Comment: @David $d(y,0.0001)=|y-0.0001|$.

Comment: OK, so if this expression is ${}<0.0000001$, then what are the possible values for $y$?

Comment: @David Oh! So the value for variable $y$ is determined by the metric it is in that is $<\epsilon$?!

Comment: I think you have the idea though I'm not certain precisely what you are saying in your last comment.  Did you find the values of $y$ in the recent example?

Comment: @David $0.0001001>y>0.0000999$?

Comment: Right, and so $B_d(0.0001,0.0000001)$ is the set of all those values.

Comment: @David Ah! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you know what an epsilon-delta proof is (I think you do by looking at some recent answers of yours), then you should know the use of $\epsilon$. If not, then the question is kind of broad. What part of the concept do you not understand?